# case statement two string fields interacting

Tags: qgis, qgsexpression

I have situation where the values from two fields (both strings) interact to create the value of a third (also a string). This is from a simple flowchart.

I've tried using the CASE statement but I can't seem to get any variation of the below statement to work - I just seem to get NULL values.

```
CASE

WHEN "Field1" LIKE '%ValueA%' AND "Field2" LIKE '%Value1%' THEN 'RESULT1'
WHEN "Field1" LIKE '%ValueA%' AND "Field2" LIKE '%Value2%' THEN 'RESULT1'
WHEN "Field1" LIKE '%ValueA%' AND "Field2" LIKE '%Value3%' THEN 'RESULT2'
WHEN "Field1" LIKE '%ValueB%' AND "Field2" LIKE '%Value1%' THEN 'RESULT2'
WHEN "Field1" LIKE '%ValueB%' AND "Field2" LIKE '%Value2%' THEN 'RESULT2'
WHEN "Field1" LIKE '%ValueB%' AND "Field2" LIKE '%Value3%' THEN 'RESULT1'

(etc etc)

END
```

Any ideas what I may be doing wrong? Is there an alternative statement that may work better for this type of query (in total there are about 30 possible variations of the two fields yielding three different results).

Comment: Yes, one field contains a total of three strings and the other a mix of around 10 text and numeric values, all originally from drop down lists. When I originally wrote the CASE expression I set it up using `=` but that didn't seem to work either and reading around I thought it might be because the fields are strings rather than numeric fields. But I see your point re the wildcard

Comment: @Matt in all dialects of SQL `%` matches ***zero** or more* characters, while `_%` or `%_` matches ***one** or more* characters. Does the QGIS expression engine break with this quasi-standard?

Comment: My mistake, thank you for the correction!

Comment: @Matt I was actually asking, not correcting *per se* ,)

Comment: @geozelot I had misremembered and was foolish enough not to check. What you said stands for QGIS also.

Comment: Try it just with one case to see what specifically is breaking it: start with `CASE WHEN "Field1" LIKE '%ValueA%' THEN 'test'` then try `CASE WHEN "Field2" LIKE '%Value2%' THEN 'test'` and so forth to isolate the issue.

Comment: As for how to simplify that, I would use the function editor to write something using two `for` loops to iterate through valueA,B,C and value1,2,3 https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/expression.html#function-editor

Comment: Your expression is working just fine on QGIS 3.24.0. See https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNiyr.png So it may either be a bug in your version or there is something else you did not mention.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot showing some of the rows where you get NULL values?

Comment: Hi all, thanks for your feedback/advice. So it turns out that the expression works fine (as I expected) if the fields (in my above example Field1 and Field2) are set to Value Map (or Text) widgets in the form. But if the fields are set to Value Relation it doesn’t work-I guess the expression can’t see the look up tables behind.

Comment: So you are using this expression as a default value together with some value relation? That is a completely different setup you need to mention and explain.

Comment: Not sure how it’s ‘completely different’? The resulting values in the table are the same. I guess the FIDs are hiding behind the table but that isn’t obvious to the user. Sorry for my inexperience

Comment: Thanks to everyone else who provided really useful comments and feedback and helped me figure out the problem.